# Sample-Gene-Expression data storage problem in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 50 gb sample-gene expression data .I want to store this data in mysql files.Data is divided into three txt files .one is sample ,2nd is gene ,and third is a sample-gene matrix which store their expression values.

I tried with three tables,one is for sample,2nd for gene and third with two foreign keys sample id,geneid and a field exp_value .But problem is how i can store that matrix in this table.

Comment: @Michael Andrew Bentley :- i think you worked on these type of problem.Can you please help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

You have data in text files, hoping that it's already formatted with separators.  If it's formatted then it's easy to import.

If you are using linux use Konsole.   If you are using Windows use CMD.   It will take while to import it for that large file size.  You just have to wait. It's gonna be a lot of trials and errors at first.

Comment: Thank you very much...I'll try this.